# Save changes to child class properties using base class query with Entity Framework TPH patten

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a simple TPH hierarchy:

```
public abstract class UserAccount
{
    public string FirstName { get;set; }
}

public class InterpreterAccount : UserAccount
{
    public string PhoneNumber { get;set; }
}
```

and in DbContext:

```
//.......
public DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
public DbSet<InterpreterAccount> InterpreterAccounts { get; set; }
```

This code works (saves both FirstName and PhoneNumber to DB):

```
var account = _context.InterpreterAccounts.Single(i => i.Id == id);
account.FirstName = "Ivan";
account.PhoneNumber = "+123";
_context.SaveChanges();
```

And this doesn't save PhoneNumber property

```
var account = (InterpreterAccount)_context.UserAccounts.Single(i => i.Id == id);
account.FirstName = "Ivan";
account.PhoneNumber = "+123";
_context.SaveChanges();
```

But in real scenarios, the type of object is known only after it is retrieved, hence the need to query the base collection.

**So the question is:** how can I save changes to derived objects of TPH hierarchy retrieved by querying the base object collection in EF7?

Comment: Can you include the Fluent API from `OnModelCreating()`?

Answer (score 1):

...and found a solution in next 10 minutes. Still looks kinda ugly though.

To save changes to derived object retrieved via base object set, I had to 1) detach object on querying and 2) attach to collection based on it's type

```
var account = _context.UserAccounts.AsNoTracking().Single(i => i.Id == id);
account.FirstName = "Ivan";
if (account is InterpreterAccount)
{
    _context.InterpreterAccounts.Attach(account);
    ((InterpreterAccount)account).PhoneNumber = "+123";
}
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Works but involves conditional logic which seems overkill. I'd like to see it working without it.