# Update inherited Entity in Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following `BaseballDbContext` class:

```
public class BaseballDbContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<BaseballTeam> teams { get; set; }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Hitter>();
       modelBuilder.Entity<Pitcher>();
   }
}
```

And my model classes are:

```
public class BaseballTeam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string teamName { get; set; }
    public List<BaseballPlayer> players { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseballPlayer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Hitter : BaseballPlayer
{
    public int homeruns { get; set; }
}

public class Pitcher : BaseballPlayer
{
    public int strikeouts { get; set; }
}
```

Initially seeded data in the players table:

[image]

Now I want to update `name` and `homeruns` property of one of the hitters:

```
BaseballTeam team = _ctx.teams.Include(q => q.players).FirstOrDefault();
Hitter hitter = team.players.OfType<Hitter>().FirstOrDefault();
hitter.name = "Tulowitzki";  //that property will be updated
hitter.homeruns = 399;       //but that will not :(

int i = team.players.FindIndex(q => q.Id == hitter.Id);
team.players[i] = hitter;

_ctx.Update(team);
_ctx.SaveChanges();
```

After I run the code only player's name got update, but not the homeruns property:

[image]

How to update property of both child and parent class ?

Comment: Don't you need a `DbSet<BaseballPlayer>` too? See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph)

Comment: No, I do not need it. It is an abstract class.

Comment: This might be worth a shot: `_ctx.Entry(team).State = EntityState.Modified` put it before the update call.

Comment: Tried, and unfortunately it does not solve the problem.

Comment: As I understand that issue is already fixed, and will be available with next release https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/commit/8c1d2581f2339f30eda6ad9df6728944e3a7f230

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this answer but this is a **workaround**: [Save changes to child class properties using base class query with Entity Framework TPH patten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402298/save-changes-to-child-class-properties-using-base-class-query-with-entity-framewOnly) :

**Do Not track changes using AsNoTracking()**

```
using (var context = new BaseballDbContext())
{
    var team = context.teams.Include(q => q.players).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
    var hitter = team.players.OfType<Hitter>().FirstOrDefault();
    hitter.name = "Donaldson";
    hitter.homeruns = 999;
    context.Update(team);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I think you should have a look at the [opened issues related to inheritance](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=inheritance) and may be open a new issue

Comment: Sure... That s why maybe you have to open an issue... I think because you are not tracking the changes, when you perform the update the context verify every property on every object but really not sure